# Magento No shipping method is shown in guest checkout

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.7

I am having strange problem in my checkout page. I am using one step checkout, None of the shipping methods are not shown when trying with guest checkout.But as soon as i  try to checkout with login, it shows all the shipping methods. When i was trying to debug i found that Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available::getShippingRates() is returning blank array when im not logged in . I am using magento 1.7 CE. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks ,

Answer (score 2):

SOme suggestions:
Can you please check in the following log files if there is any problems:

- var/log/exception.log
- var/log/system.log
- and your php log

Comment: The thing i was missing is that it didnt set the default country in one step checkout configuration